# Cascading WMS with decorations

Tags: geoserver, wms, layouts

I am trying to cascade my own GeoServer in order to directly display the decorations (without the need to add &format_options=layout:layout_name in the request because I can't modify the request on the client side).

What I did was I added the Capabilities URL like this:

`http://localhost:8080/geoserver/workspace/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=workspace%3Alayer_name&format_options=layout:layout_name`

And I was hoping that the store that I created this way would directly display the decorations when requested from OpenLayers, but I can only see the layer when requesting - without the decorations.
Note: The layout file works correctly when I add it in the URL for the layer preview.

What am I doing wrong? Is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each OGC request has a number of parameters that are officially supported in it, by specification (see the WMS standard, available online). All other parameters must be ignored (again, by specification).

In your case, the `format_options` parameter is meant to be used only in GetMap, so it will be simply ignored when you do a GetCapabilities request.

There is an extension, called [parameters extractor](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/params-extractor/index.html), that is often used to address these cases. One of its functionalities is to echo selected parameters from GetCapabilities request to the backlinks in the GetCapabilities response, so that clients unware of them will still use them.

As an alternative, with the same module, you can put an extra bit in the path that can be configured to become the "format options" of your liking.

See the module documentation for more details.